# Fading VStacks in and Out when @Published value changes in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to get my head around animating a condition in which a VStack is removed and an additional VStack appears. At the minute `subscriptionProduct` is loaded as the NavigationStack pushes in the view which means as the body is sliding in there is a quick change in views, ideally I would like VStack 1 to fade out and then VStack 2 to fade in.

I have looked at a Bool approach but not sure how to apply the animation to both.

```
@EnvironmentObject var subscriptionManager: SubscriptionManager

var body: some View {
    if(subscriptionManager.subscriptionProduct != nil){
        // VStack 1
        VStack{}
    }else {
        // VStack 2
        VStack{}
    }
    
}
```

Comment: there is no `NavigationStack` in your code, there is no `animation` in your code,
 there is no minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code will help you, you can adjust the animation type and duration to suit your needs. You can also add additional animations to the VStacks themselves, such as fading animations or scaling animations.

```
@EnvironmentObject var subscriptionManager: SubscriptionManager


@State private var isVStack1Visible = true

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if isVStack1Visible {
            // VStack 1
            VStack{}
        } else {
            // VStack 2
            VStack{}
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
            isVStack1Visible = subscriptionManager.subscriptionProduct != nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I followed your example but embedded both VStack inside a ZStack, from there added the modifier .animation(.easeIn, value: subscriptionManager.productsReady) to the ZStack. Just needed to update the productsReady bool when the product was ready

Comment: yes you can use it and It's a good solution @ORStudios

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add the animation by surrounding both VStack in a ZStack and then adding the modifer `.animation(.easeIn, value: subscriptionManager.productsReady)` to the ZStack.

Now when the bool `productsReady`is updated to true the Views change as needed.

```
@EnvironmentObject var subscriptionManager: SubscriptionManager

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if(subscriptionManager.subscriptionProduct != nil){
            // VStack 1
            VStack{}
        }else {
            // VStack 2
            VStack{}
        }
    }.animation(.easeIn, value: subscriptionManager.productsReady)
    
}
```